# Title of Lady for an Italian Married woman

Tags: word-usage

Is an Italian married woman addressed as "Lady".
such as, Lady Judy, or Lady Natalie....

I have tried google, and every search engine.

Comment: Do people in England actually address married women with *Lady*? They certainly don't in the US... As far as I know there's nothing of the sort in Italian (there was the old *signora/signorina* but it hasn't been in use for quite a while now)

Comment: Lady is not an Italian word, and while it can be used to address a married woman in English, it doesn't necessarily have that connotation.

Comment: Isn't a married woman addressed with _Ms._, in English?

Comment: No, she's not, a married woman is traditionally addressed as Mrs (_Mistress_).

Comment: A married woman is addressed to as *signora*. Would you please try and improve your question? The reference to *Lady* makes little sense, because that title is *not* used for a married woman in English, unless she's married to a peer or is a peer herself.

Answer (score 2):

An italian married woman is usually addressed as "signora" followed by her surname/family name or the surname/family name of her husband.

Comment: Is using the family name of the husband current usage? If you tried that with my mother, you wouldn't end up well (either now or in the 80s when people at the office tried to make her sign as such). Also, using *signora* is not specific to married women as far as I can tell.

Comment: In Italy it is still in current use and socially accepted. It is also preferred in case you don't know precisely her surname.

Comment: Usually you address an unmarried woman with "signorina" instead of "signora", and usually an unmarried woman prefer to be called "signorina".

Comment: As I said, I've never heard it used in my life and I would consider it misogynist and archaic (both using the husband's last name and using *signorina* for an unmarried woman), but it's my experience against yours.

Comment: As said in Treccani vocabulary ( www.treccani.it/vocabolario/signora www.treccani.it/vocabolario/signorina ) they are obviously better used in a non-familiar contest (as mush as "lady"), because otherwise it's used the only (first) name

Comment: As a counterpoint, here is what the Treccani's *Domande e risposte* has to say about the usage of *signorina* http://www.treccani.it/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/lessico/lessico_219.html . I still contend that it is not socially acceptable, at least not everywhere.

Comment: I agree that using _Signora_ as opposed to _Signorina_ it is sexist but unfortunately it's very common. The patriarchal usage of the husband's surname instead of the maiden name is less common but it's still not unusual at all. I would say that the husband's surname has already become a minority thing but indifference to _Signora_ vs _Signorina_ has not yet become mainstream.

Answer (score 0):

Lady in the UK is a title given to women as members of the British nobility or as part of the British honours system. Outside of that context it would never be used in daily life to address someone. In Italian, Signora or Signorina is the polite, normal way to address someone you don't know or with whom you have a formal relationship.